# How to make a Phonegap plugins installer batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cordova

I'm trying to develop a batch file that runs a lot of commands of the type of "phonegap local plugin add" for automate the Phonegap plugin installation process when I want to share my app.

I found the following solution developed in linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

//this hook installs all your plugins

// add your plugins to this list--either 
// the identifier, the filesystem location 
// or the URL
var pluginlist = [
    "org.apache.cordova.device",
    "org.apache.cordova.device-motion",
    "org.apache.cordova.device-orientation",
    "org.apache.cordova.geolocation",
    "https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/"
];

// no need to configure below

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
  sys.puts(stdout)
}

pluginlist.forEach(function(plug) {
   exec("cordova plugin add " + plug, puts);
});
```

I'm trying to develop this code in a Windows batch file. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a script POV this may be close:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
    "org.apache.cordova.device"
    "org.apache.cordova.device-motion"
    "org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"
    "org.apache.cordova.geolocation"
    "https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/"
) do cordova plugin add %%a
```

Comment: @axl The edit that you tried to make only applies if cordova is a batch file, and it wasn't stated that cordova was a batch file.  A `call` command isn't needed with `.exe` or `.com` files.